# How can I render the personal contact form in node twig template?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-contact-form

My website has many products posted by different people. In each node.html.twig, How can i show the personal contact form for each owner?
I use the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) to render form.
Suppose I have "author" variable (`Drupal\user\Entity`) for use.

I try in hook_preprocess_node:

```
function MY_thEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
$message = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('contact_message')->create([
  'contact_form' => 'personal',
  'recipient' => $user->id(),
]);

$form = \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder::getForm($message);
$form['#title'] = $this->t('Contact @username', ['@username' => $user->getDisplayName()]);
$form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.permissions';
$variables['personal_form'] = drupal_render($form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Renderer` service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/class/Renderer/8.4.x) instead of <del>`drupal_render()`</del> which is deprecated, e.g.

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for node templates.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_node()
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $message = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('contact_message')->create([
    'contact_form' => 'personal',
    'recipient' => $user->id(),
  ]);

  $form = \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder::getForm($message);
  $form['#title'] = $this->t('Contact @username', ['@username' => $user->getDisplayName()]);
  $form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.permissions';
  $variables['personal_form'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($form);
}
```